# Malware scan on processed executables during invocation of Microsoft Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

If I use `Microsoft Azure Functions` in order to process executable PE files, does it detect potentially malicious executables and aborts my processing?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Azure app service and Functions app do not provide antimalware feature to detect and remove potentially malicious files automatically.

Here is [a feedback: Antimalware feature on Web Apps (App Service)](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/17919064-antimalware-feature-on-web-apps-app-service), you can check and vote for it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Are you familiar with Azure Functions? Could you also state something about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723981/invocation-of-kernel32-createfilemapping-on-microsoft-azure-functions