# Invocation of Kernel32.CreateFileMapping on Microsoft Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Does `Microsoft Azure Functions` allow to invoke specific Win API functions (e.g.: `Kernel32.CreateFileMapping`) on the underlying Operating System?

Comment: Is this something that you tried and failed on, or that you did not try and are curious whether it would work?

Comment: @DavidEbbo I didn't try it, yet. Before I invest much effort I ask some of you experts who already know it.